# Restore Previous Command in Oracle

Tags: oracle, command

Is there is an easy way to access the previous commands entered in Oracle? For example, when using a Linux terminal, one can press the "up arrow" key and traverse through the command history. Does Oracle offer a similar convenient feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not built in, no.

In DOS SQL*PLUS this happens for you (i.e. up arrow goes to the prior command).

in linux sql*plus it does not. Having said that, there is a nice utility on linux called `rlwrap` that can do it for us. first install that utility and then set an alias (stick this in your .profile so that you don't have to run it every time you open a shell):

```
oracle@dazza-linux64:~$ alias sqlplus='rlwrap sqlplus'
```

now whenever you start sql*plus:

```
oracle@dazza-linux64:~$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

you'll get the up/down arrow functionality you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Unfortunately my Oracle account is on an enterprise system in a University so I do not believe I can install 'rlwrap'. I should have been clearer about this in my question. Thank you anyway for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows client there are two SQL*Plus command line utilities: one that's DOS-looking (`sqlplus.exe`) and one that's Windows-looking (`sqlplusw.exe`). The DOS-type version has the "uparrow" feature, plus you can press F7 for a list of previous commands, but note that it doesn't play well with multi-line commands.

The Windows-type version doesn't support uparrow or F7, but you can highlight a prior query, and copy/paste. You can also do the *nix trick of right-clicking while still holding down the left button to do the immediate copy/paste. It behaves well with multi-line commands but I have to admit I'd really love to have the uparrow here too :)

Comment: sqlplusw has been deprecated long ago. as far as I remember it's not even present in 11g

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I didn't realize. At my main Oracle customer we've been using Oracle 11g server but with the 9i client (or maybe even the 8i) for at least a couple years. It works fine, except when it causes me to make an embarassing post here on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a function of "Oracle" per se, it's a function of the client and/or OS.  If I run SQL*Plus on Windows, for example, the up/down arrow functions as you describe.